# making a bigger text box on a second row of the form

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have two rows of text boxes on my form. The first rows has three text boxes and the next row, I only want one text box that has a width of 100%. Below is my code:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>First Name</label><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fName" CssClass="textboxsizeLarge borderText" ></asp:TextBox></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
             <label>Middle Name</label><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="MdName" CssClass="textBoxSizMd borderText" ></asp:TextBox></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Last Name</label><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="lname"  CssClass="textboxsizeLarge borderText" ></asp:TextBox></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>Address1</label><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="address1" CssClass="borderText textboxsizebig" ></asp:TextBox></div>
</div>
```

I want the address1 text box to be up to 80% of the screen width, but it is going up to 40%. I am using Bootstrap for this purpose.

Below is the screen shot of how the second address1 text box looks like:

[image]

I want address1 to be all the way to the beginning of Last Name text box

Below is my style sheet:

```
.textboxsizeLarge{

    width:60%;
}

.textBoxSizMd {
    width: 30%;
}
.textboxsizebig {
    width: 100%;
}

.borderText {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

This is how I am using bootstrap in my site.master in case bootstrap is not working properly. I am not sure if I need to add anything additional in my site.master page. below is the partial site.master code. I also pasted the entire code after that.

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>

                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" path="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js" />

                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Below is my entire sire.master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="IdentityCheckApp.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"   href="Content/Site.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" path="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>


                    <div><h1 class="h1top"></h1></div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-top px-5 mb-3">
                        <img src="images/azx.png" class="logo mr-3" />
                        <h4>test company</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div><h1 class="h1bottom"></h1></div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could this be because of the `col-md-3` class in the last row? I don't use bootstrap but what if you use `col-md-2` for example?

Comment: I tried col-md-2 and col-md-3 and col-md-12, but the text box size is not increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap, all you have to do is to **make your desire column [`col-*-12`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)**. Bootstrap grid stands for 12 columns in general so if you want to make your element fill the whole row, **you should tell it to get all 12 of them**.

Just like this:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>Address1</label><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="address1" CssClass="borderText textboxsizebig col-md-12" ></asp:TextBox></div>
</div>
```

### UPDATE

So in order to reproduce your problem, I just used your current code for more illustration and applied HTML attributes instead of ASP ones (sorry for that).

In order to make this work, you need to add two `col-md-12` to your elements, one for your wrapper `div` and another for your `input`. The first one will tell your whole div to fit the `row` and the second one will make your input fit the remaining `width` (For better results see it in full-page).

```css
.row {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>First Name</label><br />
    <input runat="server" ID="fName" class="textboxsizeLarge borderText" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Middle Name</label><br />
    <input runat="server" ID="MdName" class="textBoxSizMd borderText" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Last Name</label><br />
    <input runat="server" ID="lname" class="textboxsizeLarge borderText" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>Address1</label><br />
    <input runat="server" ID="address1" class="borderText textboxsizebig col-md-12" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I was thinking the other way around in my comment to the OP's question hehe, this is probably the answer.

Comment: adding col-md-12 did not make any difference. It made the text box slightly bigger and thats it. I added a new picture of bigger text box in my original post

Comment: I removed the stylesheet from address1 textbox. By Main Container, you mean my site.master class. I pasted both the partial and full code of my site.master page in my original post

Comment: THANK YOU!! It worked. I am not sure what was I doing wrong. I was so frustrated that I was gong to use flexbox.

Comment: @Anjali Actually the combination of `col-md-12` on parent and `width: 100%;` on `input` should work as well. But your first provided code does not work since you just told the bootstrap to fill 2 columns only.

Comment: As soon as I remove col-md-12 from <input> , text box size becomes smaller

Comment: @Anjali Are you sure the stylesheet is applying correctly? Can you inspect it in the dev tool?

Comment: You are right. something is wrong with my stylesheet. Thanks.